# Airflow doesn't execute DAG's at midnight

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I did a DAG's with the following configuration:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0, 0, minute=1),
    'email': ['francisco.salazar.12@sansano.usm.cl'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'max_active_runs': 1, 
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'provide_context': True 
}

dag = DAG(
    'terralink_environmetal_darksky',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Extract Data from Darksky API',
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval='31 * * * *',
)
```

The issue is that `scheduler` works correctly and execute DAG run at every hour that I defined in `schedule_inverval` (in minute 31 of every hour) BUT in midnight or the last execution of the day (scheduled at 00:31:00 for the next day) the DAG execution is not triggered.

I think that is a problem based on `start_date` but I don't know yet how to define this parameter in order to avoid the problem.

Comment: I agree it's probably related to your dynamic `start_date`, I'd try to use a hardcoded start date like `'start_date': 'datetime(2020, 3, 23)`. Airflow recommends against dynamic values as noted in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date. If you really want, I'd at least do `.days_ago(2)` like most of the Airflow example DAGs do. Basically, the start date should be bigger than your schedule interval (so 8 days if it was weekly) if you want the most recent DAG run to kick off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow recommends to state a fixed start`start_date` for your DAG. start_date is mainly for the purpose to specify when do you want your DAG to start running for the very first time. `schedule_interval` will be the most relevant one after the start_date did its purpose or (if you do not need to backfill or reset your dag).